# deploy redmine on heroku - heroku run rake db:migrate -> and I got DEPRECATION WARNING

Tags: heroku, redmine

I'm trying to deploy redmine folowing this tutorial, but when I run this command
heroku run rake db:migrate

I recieve this message:

> DEPRECATION WARNING:
>   You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these
>   plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in
>   your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
>   config/initializers/myplugin.rb.
>
> See the release notes for more on
>   this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)
>
> Plugins in
>   vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please,
>   put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of
>   your Redmine directory (/app/plugins)

I put the plugin folder at redmine/lib in redmine/
And nothing hapens.

Any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the ruby buildpack - it has nothing to do with your application. Deploying a stock Ruby on Rails app will display this message.

Are you getting any errors running your application?